# In in the Skyrim inventory, what do the 3 symbols mean?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I wasn't paying attention in the beginning where it explained symbols in the inventory.

Currently, I have SkyUI, but I don't think the symbols actually change.

[image: gif about it]

Next to my banded iron shield of resist fire are 3 symbols. I know the star means favorite, but what are the others?

Comment: You should consider turning this gif into a still image of what you are actually asking about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- The white diamond means that the game thinks this is the best item you own for it's slot (for armor this tends to be the item with the highest armor value).
- The yellow star is as you already figured out that you have the item favorited.
- The blue lightning bolt means it has some enchantment on it.
- As @gatherer818 mentioned there is also the possibility of a red hand, which means stolen good. You can sell stolen goods only to fences you unlocked through the thieves guild.
- a white arrow on the left of the item name (see image below) means it is currently equipped.

[image]

Comment: The diamond is the game's recommendation system suggesting that the item is the best of its type you have, the equip symbol is an arrow pointing at the item to the left which the gif cuts out.  [This image](http://skyrim-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/3863-1-13240881151.jpg) shows the equip arrows on the left and the upgrade diamonds to the right of the item.

Comment: @Namfuak you're right, I'm updating my answer. It's been quite some time since I last played skyrim, and got confused.

Answer (score 3):

The blue lightning bolt means it has a magical effect when equipped (fire resistance, given the item name).  You can see those bolts also on your rings and amulets and the robes (which almost always have a bonus to Magicka regeneration).  I can't see the other icon in your example picture, but it looks kind of like the red hand.  If it is, it's probably considered stolen and will be confiscated if you are arrested.